# Why can't I overwrite the value of an argument of an outer function if I use that variable in an if statement?

Tags: python, scope

I was writing a decorator that is initialized with an argument, and I tried setting that argument to `None` by default and then check if that argument `is None` and if so do `argument = some_default_value`. I've boiled down the issue I ran into:

This code works (it prints `None`):

```py
def outer(arg=None):
    def inner():
        print(arg)
    inner()

outer()
```

and this code works (it prints `22`):

```py
def outer(arg=None):
    def inner():
        arg = 22
        print(arg)
    inner()

outer()
```

This code doesn't:

```py
def outer(arg=None):
    def inner():
        if arg is None:
            arg = 22
        print(arg)
    inner()

outer()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    outer()
  File "test.py", line 6, in outer
    inner()
  File "test.py", line 3, in inner
    if arg is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arg' referenced before assignment
```

Why does using the variable `arg` in an `if` statement make Python decide that it must be defined in that scope and not in an outer scope?

Comment: The `if` statement has nothing to do with this.  If a scope contains any assignment to a variable, that variable becomes local by default, unless explicitly declared `global` or `nonlocal`.  In both of your examples, there are two entirely unrelated variables named `arg`, one in `outer` and one in `inner`.

Comment: Try the same with: def inner(arg) / inner(arg). You have to transmit the arg variable because it is not global. In "inner()" there is no arg variable, before you create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a variable is determined when the function is defined. By assigning to `arg`, you make `arg` a local variable throughout the scope local to `inner`, which means `if arg is None` is now testing the as-yet undefined local variable `arg`, not the non-local variable defined by `outer`. (Put another way, the *presence* of an assignment statement in the body of the function makes the *name* local, not the actual *execution* of the statement, which creates the variable by that name.)

You could fix that by declaring `arg` as non-local in the body of `inner`:

```
def outer(arg=None):
    def inner():
        nonlocal arg

        if arg is None:
            arg = 22
        print(arg)
    inner()

outer()
```

though be aware that the change to `arg` is visible after the call to `inner` as well, because it is `outer`'s local variable `arg` that you changed.